# Invalid field type - ftFMTBcd

Tags: delphi

This code raises an exception "Invalid field type" on line "CreateDataset". What is my mistake?

```pascal
TQuery = class(TClientDataSet)

...
procedure TQuery.CreateField();
begin
  FieldDefs.Add('SOME_FIELD', ftFMTBcd, 8, False);
  CreateDataset;
end;
```

Comment: Compiles/runs fine here with D2007.

Comment: DB in uses exists, code compiles. Exception raising in runtime, whhen call CreateField();

Comment: @user - Create a **blank** project and test this: `uses db, dbclient;` `type TQuery=class(TClientDataSet) protected procedure CreateField;end;` Implement `CreateField` as in the question. Then run this: `with TQuery.Create(nil) do CreateField;` Does it fail?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz - yes, it fails, i did it like you recomended. We find decision. On computer, where fails was registered midas.dll of 5 version. Our applicvation must use 7 version of midas.dll. Tthank you for your participation!

Comment: Looks as if you are on Delphi 5 [In Delphi 5 and earlier versions, the numeric field type is mapped to either the ftInteger or ftFloat because the ftFMTBcd is not available in those Delphi releases](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.1/mergedprojects/ade/sec7/tadstable_7.htm)